# How to create pyspark column and fill it recursively?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to add a column to an existing pyspark dataframe. However, the value in the column is depending on the value in the previous row of the same column. The first row of the column equals a fixed value, let's say 0 and for `row_numbers > 1`, the value in the column equals the value of the previous row in the same column + value from other row. Currently, I use the following code for it:

```
df.withColumn("new_column", F.when(F.col("row_num") == 1, 0)
.otherwise(F.lag(F.col("new_column")).over(window_spec) + F.col("other_column"))
```

Here, `window_spec` is defined by `window_spec = Window.orderBy("row_num")`.

The sample data generated below can be used to test the code:

```
df = [(1, 10), (2, 5), (3, 7), (4, 3)]
columns = ["row_num", "other_column"]
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
| row_num | other_column | new_column |
| --------| -------------| ---------- |
| 1       | 10           | 0          |
| 2       | 5            | 0 + 5 = 5  | 
| 3       | 7            | 5 + 7 = 12 |
| 4       | 3            | 12 + 3 = 15|
```

However, my code only returns `null` values for `row_numbers > 1` or an error message. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: can you post your `window_spec` ?

Comment: can you provide your sample code and input so that others can replicate.

Comment: `F.lag(F.col("new_column"))`  should this be `F.lag(F.col("other_column"))`  ??

Comment: @user238607 no, it should be previous row value of current new column + current row value of other column

Comment: But there is a problem there, `new_column` will only be created after that statement is fully executed. You can't refer to `new_column` before it is created in the same statement.

Comment: that's my whole question, how do I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use recursion with Window functions. But it seems it's not required here. Simply use a cumulative sum:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.orderBy("row_num")

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "new_column",
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("row_num") > 1, F.col("other_column"))).over(w)
)

df2.show()
#+-------+------------+----------+
#|row_num|other_column|new_column|
#+-------+------------+----------+
#|      1|          10|      null|
#|      2|           5|         5|
#|      3|           7|        12|
#|      4|           3|        15|
#+-------+------------+----------+
```